# php check name contains string and checkout more names

Tags: php

I made a simple function to check if array strings contain a certain name. However, since the names are getting more and more, I have to duplicate `elseif` all the time. If someone could help me to improve me function please? I'd like to check $arr names.

if the array looks like `$arr = array('PDF', 'PSD', 'PNG', 'GIF', 'Mp3', 'JPG'....);`

`$i` can be counted from `mysql`

```
 function checkname($arr, $name1, $name2, $name3......... ){
        if (strpos($arr, $name1) !== false) {
            return $name1;
        }elseif(strpos($arr, $name2) !== false){
            return $name2;

        ..............


        }else{
            return ' ';
        }
    }


checkname($arr[$i], 'PDF', 'PSD', 'PNG'........);
```

Comment: Why don't you pass an array of names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest [`array_slice()`](http://www.php.net/array_slice) and [`func_get_args()`](http://www.php.net/func_get_args) to solve your argument problem?

```
<?php
    function checkname($arr, $name) {
        foreach (array_slice(func_get_args(), 1) as $name) {
            if (strpos($arr, $name) !== false) {
                return $name;
            }
        }

        return '';
    }
?>
```

..alternately, to solve it into infinity (or however many array values your memory can handle) why not pass an array, and simply do the following:

```
<?php
    function checkname($arr, $names) {
        foreach ($names as $name) {
            if (strpos($arr, $name) !== false) {
                return $name;
            }
        }

        return '';
    }

    checkname($arr[$i], array('PDF', 'PSD', 'PNG'));
?>
```

**Note**:

Your current code checks for the position of `PDF`, `PSD`, `PNG` etc., *anywhere* in your name (**in uppercase!!**), so `MYPNG.PHP` would go through fine, and `doge.png` would fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot! will tick this one :-)

Comment: @olo Make sure you check the latest edit - it'd always return `$name` if anything else wasn't returned.

Answer (score 1):

Are you set on using a function with a dynamic number of parameters? I would pass two string arrays a parameters.

```
function checkname($arr, $names){
    foreach ($names as $value)
        if (in_array(strtoupper($value), $arr))
            return $value;
}
```

As mentioned in other comments, you will need to cleanse your input. It appears you database is storing your file types in upper case. Fell free to use `strtoupper` if this is true.